# Splitting a csv file and post it in URL

Tags: javascript, php, csv, sms-gateway

I am having a csv file where 10000 or more numbers can be present. Now i want to send sms to those number with my sms gateway. Now the problem is only 40 numbers can be send one time. So how will upload my csv and how will i split that csv to send sms. I use `curl` method to send to post.

For uploading csv file i use

```
<input type="text" id="concc1" name="concc1">
<script>
$("#filecsv").change(function(e) {
var ext = $("input#filecsv").val().split(".").pop().toLowerCase();

if($.inArray(ext, ["csv"]) == -1) {
alert('Upload CSV');
return false;
}

if (e.target.files != undefined) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
var csvval=e.target.result.split("\r\n\t");
var csvvalue=csvval[0].split(",");
var inputrad="";
for(var i=0;i<csvvalue.length;i++)
{
var temp=csvvalue[i];
var inputrad=inputrad+""+temp;
var newString = inputrad.replace(/[\s]+/g, ",");
    var newString1 = newString.replace(/,\s*$/, "");
}
//$("#give").html(newString1);
document.getElementById("conc").value=newString1;

var lines= e.target.result.split("\r\n\t");
for (var i= lines.length; i-->0;)
    if (lines[i].match(/"/g).length%2===1)
        lines.splice(i-1, 2, lines[i-1]+lines[i]);
var rowsn= lines.length;

document.getElementById("concc1").value=lines;

};
reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0));

}

return false;

});

</script>
```

After that i use to post the output

```
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//echo "Message sent Successfully";

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
$daat=$url . $fields_string;
//$str = curl_exec($ch);
//echo $daat;
curl_close($ch);
```

Now i can send 40 number at a time with this method. But i want to send 10000+ so need to split the file having 40 numbers then only i can send the lot.  What i thing is I need to run cronjob but before that i need to split the file make it ready for post.

Comment: I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [redit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, Now i have edited my question if you can help me up.